# Pattern matching against record syntax

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Consider the following data definition:

```
data Foo = A{field::Int}
         | B{field::Int}
         | C
         | D
```

Now let's say we want to write a function that takes a `Foo` and increases `field` if it exists, and leave it unchanged otherwise:

```
incFoo :: Foo -> Foo
incFoo A{field=n} = A{field=n+1}
incFoo B{field=n} = B{field=n+1}
incFoo x = x
```

This naive approach leads to some code duplication. But the fact that both `A` and `B` shares `field` allows us to rewrite it:

```
incFoo :: Foo -> Foo
incFoo x | hasField x, n <- field x = x{field=n+1}
incFoo x = x

hasField A{} = True
hasField B{} = True
hasField _ = False
```

Less elegant, but that's defiantly easier to maintain when the actual manipulation is complex. The key feature here is `x{field=n+1}` - record syntax allows us to "update" `field` without specifying `x`'s type. Considering this, I'd expect something similar to the following syntax (which is not supported):

```
incFoo :: Foo -> Foo
incFoo x{field=n} = x{field=n+1}
incFoo x = x
```

I've considered using View Patterns, but since `field` is a partial function (`field C` raises an error) it'll require wrapping it in more boilerplate code.

So my question is: why there's no support for the above syntax, and is there any elegant way of implementing a similar behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you can't do this is because in Haskell, records are inherently second class. They always must be wrapped in a constructor. So in order to have this work as intended you either must use an individual case for each constructor, or use a record substitute.

One possible solution is to use lenses. I'll use the implementation of lenses `lens` since `lens-family-th` doesn't seem to handle duplicate field names.

```
import Control.Lens

data Foo = A {_f :: Int}
         | B {_f :: Int}
         deriving Show
makeLenses ''Foo

foo :: Foo -> Foo
foo = f %~ (+1)
```

And then we can use it like this

```
> foo (A 1)
  A{_f = 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not familiar with `lens` - will this approach still work if we'd add a third constructor `C` without `_f`?

Comment: @Benesh Indeed, `makeLenses` will make lenses that work over all constructors and behave as `id` on constructors without the relevant `_f` field :)

Comment: Technically those then are not lenses, but traversals, which here mainly means they are missing those lens operations that don't make sense for a not-always-defined field.